# Share widgets not showing on wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Could someone tell me why social sharing widgets won't appear on the following blog:

http://geckomonitor.com/blog/

I've added them in wp-admin and activated etc. I've tried to add sharethis and addthis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you install a widget, apart from activating it, you also need to place it in a certain area on your site.

To do that, login to your Wordpress backend, and select Appearance > Widgets.

If you can't see that menu-item, that means the theme you're using doesn't support widgets. You'll have to make sure it supports it before you can use your widget.

If you can see that menu-item, you'll probably see your widget in the list of 'Available widgets'. Just drag it to a region on the right and it will appear on your site.

You can find more info on Wordpress widgets here: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets